# PHP session variable is different in chrome

Tags: php, session

I created login form inside index.php starting with the session variable.

```
session_start()
$_SESSION["token"] = rand(1000, 9999);
```

Sending the form data and session variable via ajax

```
$( "#login-button" ).click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var form = $('form#login-form')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append("token", "<?php echo $_SESSION["token"]; ?>");

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'user_login.php',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
        },
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
```

});

Inside user_login.php i check the post token and session token, and if it's different throw the error.

```
<?php
session_start()

if(!empty($_SESSION["token"]) && !empty($_POST["token"]) && $_SESSION["token"] == $_POST["token"]) 
{
    //checking the formdata variables here for login
}
else {
    echo "SESSION: " . $_SESSION["token"];
    echo " TOKEN " . $_POST["token"];
}
?>
```

In Google Chrome i get this msg:
[image]

in firefox and edge still working.

Why is it different in chrome?

Comment: that's not the result that you wanted? generate a random number and save it on a session ?

Comment: Can you tell us what do you want ? Or replace `rand(1000, 9999)` by a fixed value (just for this example)

Comment: I want to get the same number what i sent like in firefox. SESSION: 1260 TOKEN 1260

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed the .htaccess redirect rules and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
```

This is not a good thing to do because `session_start`must first of all output (like `echo` or html).

Check if `session_start();` is first and write :

```
<?php
session_start();

//your code.
```

Comment: It's ok, but not fix my problem.